# How can avoid this "A potentially dangerous Request"

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtPickUpOrderInstruction="...x the mail
1 x the mirrorValidateRequest="false".                                     2. I have too many textboxes so `Server.HtmlEncode(TestString);`.Method is not possible.Its development is over.Re work i have to reduce.

But i want to restrict the user to enter these special characters?(Scripts or function-in master page that will do the same)

Comment: The answer provided on the linked thread is exactly what you need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tagmapping for this.Check out the following links for more detail

[Tag mapping in ASP.NET](http://madskristensen.net/post/Tag-mapping-in-ASPNET.aspx)

[tagMapping Element for pages (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164641.aspx)

Comment: Than You for the replay....i want to show user there is some special characters..How can i do that

Comment: Have you checked the first link